# Proof using GCDs

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given $a, b, c \in \mathbb Z$, no more than one of which is zero.

Let $g_a$ denote $\gcd(a,c)$.

Let $g_b$ denote $\gcd(b,c)$.

Also given that $a, b$ relatively prime.

Prove that $\gcd(g_a,g_b) = 1$.

I know that from the given information I can say that:

$ax_1 + by_1 = 1$

$ax_2 + cy_2 = g_a$

$bx_3 + cy_3 = g_b$

But now I'm not sure what to do with this. I've tried rearranging these a few ways but every time I seem to come to a dead end. Any push in the right direction would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Let $d$ be a common divisor of $g_a$ and $g_b$. Then $d$ divides $a$ because $g_a$ divides $a$. Likewise, $d$ divides $b$. Therefore, $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$ and so $d=1$ because $gcd(a,b) = 1$. This implies that $gcd(g_a,g_b) = 1$.

Comment: Wow I was clearly completely overthinking this. Thank you!!